# An approach towards achieving non-linear interpolation?

Tags: algorithm, interpolation, bezier, curve

I need to implement a method for non-linear interpolation between values, ease-in, ease-out, general easing curves as well as user defined curves.

I have a basic idea of how to do this - but I am not sure if it will be the most efficient solution. My idea is basically as follows:

Use a 2D cubic, quadratic or n-th order Bezier curve to control the interpolation. Traverse through the curve linearly to get the non-linear Y component, and use that to value to feed a simple linear interpolation method:

```
value = v1 + (v2 - v1) * t;
```

Where t is the non-linear Y component of the control curve.

This allows for custom, user defined methods for interpolation, but it comes at a cost, the cost of one non-linear interpolation is equal to:

> 1 + 2 * (n-1)

total interpolations, where n is the order, or number of control points of the control curve.

I am NO MATHEMATICIAN, this is the best I could come up with, so my question is if there is a better solution?

EDIT: I am probably not explaining it right, I am not a native speaker, so here is something hopefully everyone will understand:
[image: control curve interpolation]

Comment: A better solution for what, specifically?  Interpolation in general, or just a more-efficient Bezier algorithm? What are your constraints?

Comment: How will you create the cubic or quadrating cureve to "control the interpolation"? Just guessing?

Comment: @DanW - the changing slope of the curve is used as t for the interpolation, basically instead of getting linear change from v1 to v2, the "position" of the interpolated value is dictated by the control curve's Y component.

Comment: A bezier-curve is a perfect example of a non-linear interpolation.  If you want an object to traverse the curve at a constant speed, see [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14985/determine-arc-length-of-a-catmull-rom-spline/14995#14995).  Otherwise, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - actually, your link is helpful in another are, so thanks for bringing it up, however it is not the topic of this question, see the image I added, perhaps it will get clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Re your edit: I still don't understand why a normal bezier curve doesn't fit your requirements.  If you're worried about it not being strictly-increasing, see [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26391/is-there-a-family-of-monotonically-non-decreasing-noise-functions).  Otherwise, with the information we're given, "just use a bezier curve" (or any other spline) is the best answer we can give.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I need to be able to use different curves for controlling the interpolation between two values, for example in animation or drawing gradients and stuff line that. The example above is of easy-in animation, animation starts slowly and rapidly increases its speed and then slow down again, this is what I need to achieve, this is the method I came up with by myself, thus my question is it OK and if not, if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Look up questions on SO for ease-in/ease-out.  One simple solution for your case would be to use a [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: I don't want to use THAT particular curve only, it was just for example, but any curve with changing slope, for example I may also need to start the animation very fast and just ease it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, your `t` is actually a family of functions *f<sub>i</sub>(u)*, where both *u*, and *f<sub>i</sub>(u)* are between 0 and 1. If that is the case, it doesn't get any better than what you've already proposed.

It looks like you are worried about evaluating these *f<sub>i</sub>(u)* values during actual curve calculation. There is no avoiding the evaluation if you don't want to pre-calculate. If performance is a big issue and you don't need to be very precise, you can calculate tables of *f<sub>i</sub>(u<sub>j</sub>)* for as many *u<sub>j</sub>* values as you want (say 100 or 1000 discrete points between 0 and 1) for each of your curves, and when you need a value between your sampling points, do a simple linear interpolation of the two cached values around your desired point.

Comment: Thanks, that is all I needed to know. The idea is basically to create a family of classes, one of them is the one you described, returning values from 0 to 1, but also others the user can set other values and type, for example you may want a random number between 0 and 3, but you want control over the odds of returning any of those numbers, for example you want 70% odds for 0, 20% odds for 1, 7% odds for 2 and only 3% for 1, also to control while loops to create custom, non linear for loops and other stuff like that...